# How to choose & save files to a directory with Python 3?

Tags: python-3.x, directory, subdirectory, shutil

I'm having trouble making a subfolder for files to be stored into after choosing the Parent Folder or directory.

This is my current script:

```
import os, sys, subprocess, shutil, glob, os.path, csv

#User Chooses Folder or File Path Directory
path_new = filedialog.askdirectory()

def saveData():
   serial_number = input('Scan Barcode: ')
   folder_name = print('Folder Name:', serial_number)
   os.chdir(path_new) #Not sure if this is necessary
   if not os.path.exists(path_new):
       os.makedirs(path_new)
   print ('The data has been stored in the following directory:', path_new)
   shutil.move('file_directory/TOTAL.csv', 'chosen_directory/%s'% (serial_number))
   shutil.move('file_directory/enviro.csv', 'chosen_directory/%s' % (serial_number))
```

The script runs, but just not how I would like it to. Does anyone have any recommendations or an alternate solution to creating a folder and selecting it as the directory to have subfolders created and have files transferred into them?

Comment: In order for this question to be answered, it might be very helpful if you lay out an example path structure of what you expect. Are you having trouble calculating the path names of all files and directories involved, or in creating them?

Comment: Note your code has a **critical security vulnerability** ([path traversal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directory_traversal_attack)); it allows any shopper to write to arbitrary files in your filesystem. This is probably not what you want. Call [`os.path.basename`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/os.path.html#os.path.basename) on any user input to get a filename. In addition, make sure the input conforms to the format you expect as well.

Comment: I'm working on a GUI and just struggling with this. I expect this script to do the following: User chooses directory (makes folder with current date) --> Scan Barcode --> Makes a subfolder inside chosen directory with scanned part---> transfers files from another directory to the one that is thought to be created. This process will be done repeatedly and that's why I'd like to choose the directory once and have the script create and move the files every time "saveData" is entered.

Comment: At which step do you have problems? stackoverflow is not a code-writing service.

Comment: Understood. I'm having trouble at the end of the script. I'm beginning to think that shutil.move isn't the right command for moving the files to the chosen directory. What I'm getting instead is an empty new folder and a changed csv file to the name of the serial no.

Comment: No `shutil.move` is the right function to use. If you want, you can use the lower-level `os.rename`, but the semantics are very similar. You are getting that behavior because that's what your code does at the moment. If you include in the question examples of full pathnames for files before and after your program, you'll allow anyone to write an answer. You might even see the correct code yourself!

Comment: Thanks for the dialog, I was able to figure it out!

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my issue. If anyone else knows of a "cleaner" way of writing this out please update with a better answer. As of now this does exactly what I want.

Code:

```
import os, sys, shutil. os.path

path = filedialog.askdirectory()

def saveData():
        serial_number = input('Scan Barcode: ')
        folder_name = print('Folder Name:', serial_number)
        path_new = os.path.join(path, '%s' % (serial_number))
        if not os.path.exists(path_new):
                os.makedirs(path_new)
        shutil.move('C:/files/TOTAL.csv', path_new)
        shutil.move('C:/files/enviro.csv', path_new)
        print('The data has been stored in the following directory:', path_new)
```